# How to show customized website logo in safari "often visited"

Tags: html, ios, safari, icons

When I tap onto the address bar in safari I have a section "often visited" (german:häufig besucht) where the logos of my often visited websites are shown. However some of them, also my own websites, are shown with a standard icon. I will show the users of my website a customized icon. What do I have to do?

Here is an example (red marked):

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way this is done is through a link tag in the head of your HTML document.

For example, on that ARD website they use:

```
<link href="/ARD-144.png" rel="apple-touch-icon">
```

Which seems to be the image that is being displayed. Just replace the image with the one you want.

Comment: Check out [Apple's Developer Resources](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html) on the subject, it could be the resolution you're using.

Comment: I have checked your link and have already linked the images correctly. However it does not work. Here my website: http://www.mein-sporttagebuch.de Maybe anyone can see what is wrong... Thanks for any help!

Comment: Hey, i see your website is now working… would you mind to share what it was missing? Kinda have the same issue :D